# Getting timeslice per hour but grouping by machine ID

Tags: sumologic

```
_sourceCategory=myService
| json field=_raw "log.Log" as log_message
| json field=_raw "log.Barcode" as log_Barcode
| json field=_raw "log.MachineId" as machine_id
| where log_message contains "successfully sorted"
| count by machine_id
```

This query will give me the successful count per machine ID.

What I want is to get all the messages in the last 24 hours and get the average success rate per hour.

so instead of having

| Machine ID | Success Rate Count | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123445 | 2400 | 24H |

I get something like

| Machine ID | Success Rate Count per Hour | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123445 | 100 | 24H |

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to tag the successes versus failures before applying a timeslice using an `if` statement. Then apply the timeslice and aggregate on the fields and calcuate the ratio. Something like:

```
_sourceCategory=myService
| json field=_raw "log.Log" as log_message
| json field=_raw "log.Barcode" as log_Barcode
| json field=_raw "log.MachineId" as machine_id
| if (log_message matches "*successfully sorted*", 1, 0) as success
| timeslice 1h
| count as total_records, sum(success) as successes by _timeslice
| successes / total_records * 100 as success_rate_pct
```

Comment: This query will give me a % amount of success rate per total messages. What I need is the success rate average per hour. 

So if you succeeded 80 times in 8 hours the success rate per hour would be 10